# Generating a numpy array of ones and zeros with weighted chance for ones equal 0.11

Tags: python, numpy, probability

How can I generate a size 10000 Numpy array of 1's and 0's where getting 1's is weighted by a chance of 0.11?

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy's [random choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

```
from numpy.random import choice
ratio = 0.11
draw = choice([0,1], 10000, p=[1-ratio, ratio])

# Evaluate
sum(draw)
# 1119
```